# Create array of dictionaries with same keys but different values when tapping button in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I need to create dictionaries when I tap plus or minus button in UITableViewCell for dishes in menu with two same keys: "id" and "quantity" and then create an array of dictionaries. I can make it successfully only for one dish but for 2 and more I can't.

What I did so far:

```
func didTapIncrease(_ sender: PayForOrderCell) { 
    guard let tappedIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: sender) else { return } 
    let dish = dishes[tappedIndexPath.row]
    let dishId = dish.id
    sender.quantityValue += 1
    dict["id"] = dishId
    dict["quantity"] = sender.quantityValue

    if !items.contains { $0 == dict} { 
        items.append(dict) 
    } else { 
        dict.updateValue(dishId!, forKey: "id") 
    } 

    sender.priceLabel.text = "(dish.price! * sender.quantityValue) $" 
}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far.

Comment: Try to update the if condition as follows and see if it works:- `if !items.contains { $0.id == dict["id"]}`.

Comment: I have ar error Value of type '[String : Int]' has no member 'id'.

Comment: Apart from the issue it's highly recommended to use a custom struct for `quantity` and `id`. It's much more convenient than a dictionary.

Comment: closure should look like this { $0["id"] == dict["id"]}

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using simple types (like dictionary in your example) when you can create concrete type and use it.

For this situation `struct` will work fine.

```
struct Dish: Equatable {
    let id: Int
    let quantity: Int

    static func == (lhs: Dish, rhs: Dish) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

In this case, your `items` (array of dictionaries) becomes array of `Dish`es:

```
var items: [Dish] = []
```

store `Dish` is simple too (just append to the `items` array):

```
let dish = Dish(id: 0, quantity: 10)
let dish1 = Dish(id: 1, quantity: 20)
items.append(contentsOf: [dish, dish, dish, dish1])
```

and finally, filter other dishes out to get count of your added `dish` and multiply to the `price` to get final price:

```
let dishPrice = 4
let price = items.filter({ $0 == dish }).count * dishPrice // 12
```

---

If you want to keep your code the way it is, you may store only array of `id` values and get price like:

```
let price = items.filter({ $0 == dishId }).count * dish.price!
```

But as it mentioned, it is bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for such a great answer! I will try it :)

Comment: So the problem is that when I tap button, items( array of Dishes) append all this objects. But I need to override quantity property and store only one object. How to do this properly?

Comment: @VitalikKizlov, ah, finally understood why you need `quantity`. In this way, you can choose second approach – save every `dishId` in the array and filter by some concrete `dish.id` to get the `quantity` and then price.

Answer (score 0):

So here is solution that works fine for me. Everytime we tap button in UITableViewCell we do this:

```
var items: [Dish] = []
var dishh = Dish(id: dish.id!, quantity: quantity)

    if !items.contains(where: { $0.id == dish.id }) {
        items.append(dishh)
    } else if items.contains(where: { $0.id == dish.id }) {
        dishh = Dish(id: dish.id!, quantity: quantity)
        items[tappedIndexPath.row].quantity = dishh.quantity
    }
```